¿Se puede identificar si una columna es AUTO_INCREMENT en SQLite?
Necesito ayuda. Primero querría decir es mi primera vez escribiendo por aquí y no llevo programando mucho tiempo.
Estoy programando un especie de gestor de base de datos en python. Se puede consultar información, insertar, eliminar, modificar... Y también crear tablas nuevas.
Mi duda viene en que si se crea una tabla con alguna columna que sea auto_increment (como una columna id), como puedo saber que columna es auto_increment para que a la hora de insertar información no haya problemas.
Gracias de antemano

Con: SELECT * FROM sqlite_schema puedes ver el script de creación de la tabla (en el campo sql). Entonces puedes ver si el texto contiene la palabra AUTOINCREMENT
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE type="table"  and sql like  "%AUTOINCREMENT%" and tbl_name="Nombre_tabla"

Si el resultado es mayor que cero, es que la tabla tiene auto_increment

Conocer el nombre de la columna es algo más complejo. Para esto debemos saber que una columna autoincrementable en SQLite es siempre pk e Integer (ver documentación)
Para conocer esta información puedes usar:
SELECT * from pragma_table_info("nombre_tabla")

Lo cual da información de cada columna, su nombre, tipo de dato, si es null o no, el valor default y si es pk o no.
Entonces combinando ambas consultas, tenemos:
SELECT p.name AS column_name
FROM pragma_table_info('nombre_tabla') p
JOIN sqlite_master m ON m.name = 'nombre_tabla'
WHERE p.pk = 1 
  AND p.type= 'INTEGER'
  AND m.sql LIKE '%AUTOINCREMENT%';


Esta respuesta responde a una versión anterior de la pregunta. Es probable que no aplique a la nueva versión.
Para identificar si una columna es auto_increment en MySQL, puedes usar la columna extra de la tabla INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Ahí podrás identificar que la columna tenga esa propiedad si aparece la cadena auto_increment.
SELECT table_Catalog, 
       table_schema, 
       table_name, 
       column_name, 
       extra
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'MiTabla';

No sé si estés buscando algo que puedas incluir en el código al insertar, pero creo que eso sería un mal diseño.
